# How add custom attributes filter WooCommerce products admin dashboard?

Tags: woocommerce

I have a Brand attribute, can I add it to the products admin dashboard?
Found this code, it brings up a tab, but it is empty

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_filters', 'bbloomer_filter_by_custom_taxonomy_dashboard_products' );
 
function bbloomer_filter_by_custom_taxonomy_dashboard_products( $output ) {
   
  global $wp_query;
 
  $output .= wc_product_dropdown_categories( array(
   'show_option_none' => 'Filter by product tag',
   'taxonomy' => 'product_tag',
   'name' => 'product_tag',
   'selected' => isset( $wp_query->query_vars['product_tag'] ) ? $wp_query->query_vars['product_tag'] : '',
  ) );
   
  return $output;
}
```